# Apple Watch notification issue: WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class to instantiate

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, viewcontroller, apple-watch

I am getting the following error when I am trying to push my notification controller dynamically.

> 2015-03-30 13:18:53.324 MyApp WatchKit Extension[79826:1951724] Took
>   too long to show custom notification. Falling back to static.
>   2015-03-30 13:26:13.831 MyApp WatchKit Extension[79826:1957863]
>   WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class
>   '_TtC26MyApp_WatchKit_Extension19InterfaceController' to instantiate

I heard there might be a glitch, but as far as I am concern it is only occurring on the Xcode beta and not Xcode 6.2. I change the module regarding the notification storyboard to watch kit extension.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Edit : I am using the auto generated payload that apple provide when dealing with notifications for iWatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to recheck,

- When you have created a new subclass of WKUserNotificationInterfaceController, Have you selected **Watchkit extension as a target instead of iOS app target**? You can verify this by Select Project > Select Watchkit Extension Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources. Here you should see NotificationInterface.m file created earlier. If you can't see then you have selected wrong target when creating a file. Then solution is you can create a new class with correct target selected.
- In Storyboard, make sure custom class name is correctly added. Also in Payload file, category name should match with category set to storyboard scene just to avoid future errors.

Comment: This truly solved my problem! Apparently my detail view controller is not in the compile source. Adding it worked.