# How to implement a Table in iOS WatchKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm going through this simple tutorial on how to create a table in WatchKit in xcode: http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-create-table/

I'm pretty sure I've done everything properly however I'm getting this following error:

[image: screenshot of error]

Not quite sure what I've done wrong.  Any help resolving it is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: the link to full-source is in that site. Hope you created the class MinionTableRowController in your project

Comment: Yeah course  - I've done the whole course but have the error depicted in the interface controller.  I must've missed something but don't really understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have ***MinionTableRowController*** class added to your project? If you do, try adding ***!*** sign after *as*. That is,

```
let row = minionTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! MinionTableRowController
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have created a class with name MinionTableRowController but you may not have selected appropriate target. '**WatchKitTableDemo WatchKit Extension**' **Target** must be selected while creating a new class for that WatchKit extension.

Solution will be delete existing MinionTableRowController and create again with appropriate watch extension target selected. Similar answer is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367453/602997).