# Apple Watch Dynamic Local notification times out, even without any heavy code

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I am attempting to run local notifications to an apple watch, and have configured my notification controller to do nothing but print one line to the console, and then execute the completion handler.

Still, the notification fails and the static notification is launched instead. I am wondering what I am missing here? Please see attached the console output and the code for handling local notifications.

[image: As seen in the picture, the local notification handling function is executed, but it fails when reaching the completion handler]

**Edit 1:**
The notification runs fine in the apple watch simulator, but local notifications and remote notifications all fall back to the static notification on the watch if run on the actual device.

Comment: You may recheck for these two things, NotificationIntefaceController.m added to correct target and category name should match in payload and storyboard. More info, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29367453/602997

Comment: Thanks Dhawal, sadly it does seem to be a different issue, the category is specified in the localNotification object, target is correct and the category is coded in the storyboard. And as you can see the handler is actually being executed, but fails on the callback (from the screenshot)

Comment: @Alex Were you able to figure this out.

Comment: @AnandKumar Unfortunately no Anand - I deleted the project and started over on the watch os2 beta and it runs fine now. It's impossible to tell what went wrong here, the code was so clear and simple. I didn't even load any third party libraries when it failed. Dhawal above had some good comments worth checking, seems that is causing issues for other people.

Comment: It does behave unreliably at times with watchOS1 at least. I was unable to get the custom long look loaded just because I didn't have app icons for the Watch app. And now sometimes it does populate an outlet label and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @AnandKumar ha. Interesting.. I did not have app icons set at that time. I'd recommend updating to OS2, and I'll give you an upvote for the icons - might be a solution to the issue I had. Good luck!